Laravel 11 and mailtrap
I have created a Laravel 11 app and I am using mailtrap to send mails and when I send password reset link and verification mail it shows that the mail has been sent yet on the mailtrap inbox it's not there. But when I try sending a test mail it is available in the inbox. Please help.
I have tried with test mails and they are working well.The config is ok but when it comes to sending verification mails and password reset links they don't appear on the mailtrap inbox.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

Is QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync in your environment?

Yes it's there in my env file

Try to change your MAIL_MAILER to log to see if the "password reset" or "verification mail" is being sent. Check your log to confirm if Laravel is sending those emails.

i have done that and found that there is nothing on the logs

i have also tried sending test mail and it is there on the logs

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

I solved it. It happened that in my db the email field was Email and what was required was email without capital E.

Mailtrap has different hosts for Testing and Sending. Check in your configuration. So you email can't be delivered to a user and shown in an inbox at the same time. It's rather one or another

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
